# How to determine the configuration during a AppVeyor/Travis CI build?

Tags: travis-ci, appveyor

How to determine the configuration during a AppVeyor/Travis CI build?

I build my project for release and debug and on each build I would like to run my test.exe which will be in the Release folder for release build and Debug folder for debug build

Both of these attempts dont work.

It would be great to just be able to refer to the location where the build product is placed.

AppVeyor.yml

```
test_script:
  - cd Build
  - cd $env:CONFIGURATION
  - UtilsTests.exe
```

Travis.yml

```
matrix:
  include:
    - os: osx
      osx_image: xcode8.3
      compiler: clang
      script: 
        - brew update          
        - cmake . -G Xcode
        - xcodebuild
        - ./UtilsTests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `cd` command should be:

```
- cd %CONFIGURATION%
```